# Change computer (AD member) password on second computer (VM with the same SID)

Tags: active-directory, password, password-reset

I have a laptop that is connected to an AD. It tends to be slow so I converted it to a VMWare virtual machine that I can run on my home office desktop. The VM has the same SID as the physical machine.

All runs well, until I have to change the the AD password. From my VM machine, I VPN in, change the password via Ctrl-Alt-Del. Still good.

Now I take my physical laptop and physically connect to the domain network. When I try to log in, I get "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed".

As I understand it from [here](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2014/04/21/domain-trust-issues.aspx), the issue is that the physical computer has a stale password and when it tries to authenticate with the DC, the trust fails.

Is there a way to update the physical computer's AD password without being connected to the domain?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're the kind of person who thinks that company provided tools and resources are you personal playground to do with as you please. This isn't an attitude I share or appreciate. I'm hoping this question sees an expeditious closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that AD now sees the VM as the Official [TM] version of your company-issued laptop.  I'm afraid you're going to have to 'fess up to someone who has the privileges to click "reset" on the domain side, then pop the laptop out of and back into AD.  This will break the VM on your home desktop.